# Is it possible to arecord output from dummy card?

Tags: centos6, alsa

I'm trying to mix audio files via dummy card by using dmix and dsnoop:

```
aplay s1.wav &
aplay s2.wav &
arecord -f dat -t wav -d 3 result.wav
```

But is it possible?

I have only dummy card by:

```
modprobe snd-dummy
```

My ~/.asoundrc file is:

```
defaults.pcm.card 1 #dummy card

pcm.duplex {
    type asym
    playback.pcm "dmix"
    capture.pcm "dsnoop"
}

pcm.!default {
    type plug
    slave.pcm "duplex"
}
```

Running on:

```
CentOS6.5(x86_64)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `snd-dummy` driver throws away playback data, and records silence.

For a loopback device, use the `snd-aloop` driver instead.