# Piping output from aplay to arecord in centos

Tags: linux, centos, alsa

I am trying to automate some tests for a websocket client. This client connects to a server on command and the server is basically a speech to text engine. The client supports audio streaming from a microphone, such that people can record themselves in real time and transmitting it to the engine. I am running the client in a centos VM which does not have a physical sound card so I decided to simulate one using

```
modprobe snd-dummy
```

My plan is to pipe the output of

```
aplay audioFile.raw
```

to the input of

```
arecord test.raw -r 8000 -t raw
```

so that I can use that simulate the microphone feature. I read online that the file plugin for ALSA can pipe the results of one command to the next so I made the following modifications to the .asoundrc file in my root directory:

```
pcm.!default {
    type hw
    card 0
}

pcm.Ted {
       type file
       slave mySlave
       file "| arecord test.raw -r 8000 -t raw"
}

pcm_slave.mySlave {
       pcm "hw:0,0"

}

ctl.!default {
        type hw
        card 0
}
```

When I try the following command:

```
aplay audioFile.raw -D Ted
```

It seems to run fine but the output of test.raw seems to contain only silence... Does anyone know what I am doing wrong, I am very new to ALSA so if anyone can point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue Fixed, instead of using snd-dummy I used snd-aloop and audio correctly pipes refer to this question:

[Is it possible to arecord output from dummy card?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24350367/is-it-possible-to-arecord-output-from-dummy-card?rq=1)